# vb.net - automatic XML comments - ''' -- Can I change the automatic defaults?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, comments, xml-comments

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP1

in VB.NET, when I type ''' above a function, some automatic default XML comments appear:

```
''' <summary>
''' 
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
```

I would like this to be the following instead:

```
''' <summary></summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
```

Is there a way to change what appears when you type ''' above a function?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369116/change-default-xml-comment-snippet-in-visual-studio/369125#369125) says there's a way. I've asked for input here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They key is in the VBXMLDoc.xml file.  It provides templating for all of the XML comments in VB.NET.  Still have not checked if there is a solution for C#.  I went so long in wanting it for C#, but have actually just gotten used to the ugly default format.

[How to Customize the XML Comments that are inserted by the Visual Basic Code Editor?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/lisa/how-to-customize-the-xml-comments-that-are-inserted-by-the-visual-basic-code-editor)

Comment: +1 It is a pity it is XML tags only though. Even some whitespace would be good.

Comment: This has worked fine up to and including VS2013. [New question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32287626/256431) for VS2015.

Answer (score 2):

At my last place we wrote a VBA macro to insert the remarks for us and then bound it to a hotkey.  This allowed us to write ouw own custom comment blocks with additional parameter and a good deal of the information already present.

Check out this article for the full details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163757.aspx

Answer (score 1):

use GhostDoc!
:-)