# Are xml comments in VB still customizable?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, xml-comments

Since Visual Studio 2005 we could copy a file named VBXMLDoc.xml into the path: `C:\Users\*user*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\*version*\` to define the XML tags available for documentation, and which tags were inserted by default.

However, I copied the file I was using in Visual Studio Community 2013, into `C:\Users\*user*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\` and it's not working.

Has the destination path, the file format or the availability to customize the default XML tags in VB changed?

Comment: I've asked the question [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lisa/archive/2010/05/20/how-to-customize-the-xml-comments-that-are-inserted-by-the-visual-basic-code-editor.aspx?CommentPosted=true#10642141).