# C# three forward slashes: can the template be changed?

Tags: c#, xml, comments

In C#, XML comments begin with three forward slashes (///).  For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
```

Is there any way to change the generated comment, for example to add additional tags?  I thought there might be a snippet file that defines the XML, but I can't find one.  Can anyone help?

UPDATE: As far as I can tell, the first answer to the existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369116/change-default-xml-comment-snippet-in-visual-studio) simply provides a snippet that inserts code on demand.  Specifically, summ+tab+tab to insert a summary line.  It doesn't seem to involve changing the XML inserted by ///, which is what I'm looking for.

Additional answers to that question say it can be done with macro InsertDocComments (but I don't think that's what's invoked by ///, or I don't know how to cause it to be), and another answer says it can't be done.  So, if it really can't be done, oh well, but I'm still hoping.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, StyleCop's snippets for this are rather nice, since they include thrown exceptions.

Comment: The "duplicate" looks similar, but really has nothing at all to do with my question.  I'll edit the question to make the difference clear.

Answer (score 1):

I use [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) which is a free Visual Studio Extension which automatically generates xml documentation when you press `[Ctrl] + [Shift] + D` on a symbol.

As far as I am aware, you cannot override the default `///` behavior

Without the aid of external software, you could create your own custom snippet, this one has a shortcut of `ccc`

```
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Slashes</Title>
      <Author>Benjamin Thomas Blodgett</Author>
      <Shortcut>ccc</Shortcut>
      <Description>Creates xml documentation</Description>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="csharp">
        <![CDATA[/// <summary></summary>
/// <AnotherTag></AnotherTag>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>$end$]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

when going this route you can always also add the tab-stops, as I've put in below

```
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Slashes</Title>
      <Author>Benjamin Thomas Blodgett</Author>
      <Shortcut>ccc</Shortcut>
      <Description>Creates xml documentation</Description>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>summary</ID>
          <Default>Summary...</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>anothertag</ID>
          <Default>Another Tag's Value...</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>sender</ID>
          <Default>Sender Description...</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>event</ID>
          <Default>Event Args...</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp">
        <![CDATA[/// <summary> $summary$ </summary>
/// <AnotherTag> $anothertag$ </AnotherTag>
/// <param name="sender"> $sender$ </param>
/// <param name="e"> $event$ </param>$end$]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```