# Is it possible to change default XML comments in Visual Studio 2019+?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, xml-comments

Before this gets marked as duplicate, I know this question has been asked in the past [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152986/c-sharp-three-forward-slashes-can-the-template-be-changed) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369116/change-default-xml-comment-snippet-in-visual-studio), but the answers are extremely outdated and only contain workarounds and 3rd party tools.

The exact question here would be: Is it possible to change the xml comment template generated by typing "///" in Visual Studio 2019+ without using 3rd party tools? For example, add custom tags to the template?

For example, replace:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="myParam"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public int MyMethod(string myParam) { }
```

with:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="myParam"></param>
/// <myTag></myTag>
/// <returns></returns>
public int MyMethod(string myParam) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes/No, one can create a [code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2022) which can give you the basic format, but getting the parameters dynamically will be problematic.

I would suggest using a hybrid method where after running the standard xml comment that the code snippet deletes (if needed) and adds more tag(s) and other items which you may need.

---

One line Summary

This snippet just creates `<Summary> X </Summary>` and deposits a user on the X to fill it out. *It is one I created and actually use*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Single line summary</Title>
      <Shortcut>summary</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="csharp">
        <![CDATA[/// <summary>$end$</summary>]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Here it is in action, by just typing in `summary` then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to initiate it.

[image]

Comment: Yes this is also what is suggested in one of the original questions, however it does not answer the question as this doesn't modify/extend the existing template for /// nor does this method allow for the desired result

Comment: *Within Visual Studio*, Unless one is willing to make a Visual Studio Addin, I believe the hybrid method as mentioned is a viable alternative. GL