# Customize C# Standard Document Generators (XML Comments) in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, standards

- Is there any other kind of documentation generator shortcuts for C# (like `///` Generates *`function()`* Code) or any tool item (like signature in email @ outlook) in VS IDE, For following MS Standard Coding & Documentation & making understand to other co-developer working on same project.
- How to change the Format of the Generated document in visual stdio IDE by default comment format to custom comment format shown below.

Ex:

```
 1. **Default Format**

     // Name:      
     // Author:     
     // Description: <summary></summary>    
     // Parameters: <param name="abc"></praram>  
     // Returned Value: <returns></returns>

 2. **New Custom Format**

     // Application:  <project></project>  <version></version> 
     // Created Developer: <developer></developer>
     // Created Date: <date></date>  
     // Last Modified:     
     // Last Modified Developer:     
     // Parameters: <param name="abc"></praram>      
     // Return Type: <returns></returns>    
     // Description: <summary></summary>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change default XML comment snippet in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369116/change-default-xml-comment-snippet-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you mean instead of the /// comments but there are lots of options from this question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641364/c-sharp-documentation-generator

There is also these articles here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx#id0400027

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lisa/archive/2010/05/25/how-to-customize-the-xml-comments-that-are-inserted-by-the-visual-basic-code-editor.aspx

Comment: I am looking for the customization in comments (Std document generator) like other setting (editors color, fonts, tags closings,etc) can be customizable in VS. in same way i am looking for set predefined comment that needs to be generated.

Comment: @Rahul Check out the second comment in that post, there are lots of tools that let you customize them. We've used Atomineer in the past and it lets you do lots of customizations: http://www.atomineerutils.com/skins.php. I'm sure some of those free ones also have similar features

Comment: @Rahul just updated with some other articles for how to modify the xml comments

Comment: Is there any tool item like comment & remove comment tool exist in VS IDE. used when i click on it it adds predefined comments to my code..? which helps me for maintaining standard of coding every part of it.

Comment: I am actually trying to find the tool that adds the comments to my codes just like signature is Added in e-mails..

Answer (score 1):

One of the tools that let you customize the default XML comment is our [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html). You can pre-define the comment for each code element type (method, property, ...) and even for particular name or type. It's called [comment templates](http://www.helixoft.com/files/vsdocman/help/editing_comment_template.htm). Then in the code editor, right-click and select "Add XML comment". In addition, you can generate a documentation (HTML, CHM, docx, VS help, ...) from your comments with the tool.

Answer (score 0):

This is now >6 months old, but I think the answer to this question: [Change default XML comment snippet in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369116/change-default-xml-comment-snippet-in-visual-studio) will get you where you want to be. Just add your custom comment structure to the `CDATA` section, and you're all set.