# Is it possible to change the default documentation header in Visual Studio with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I add a method in a class, say like the window loaded method below,  Visual Studio will auto add the below comment when I start a triple slash comment

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Is it possible to edit the comment tempalte that `visual studio` uses?

Answer (score 1):

There are some tools that can let you configure/automate the xml comments to a reasonable degree:

-GhostDoc: http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx

-Atomineer: http://www.atomineerutils.com

Both work well from my own experience and I am affiliated with neither.

Answer (score 1):

Actually just thought about using a snippet for this and found this: [Change default XML comment snippet in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369116/change-default-xml-comment-snippet-in-visual-studio) which is exactly what I was thinking of trying. Brilliant! I'll post this answer on the related question too. Just use the process laid out here and add your own code into the `CDATA` section.