# Where is the snippet for a method's XML summary?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, xml-comments

I'm referring to the snippet that's used when typing `///` before a method.

I've found something for JavaScript (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\JavaScript\Snippets\1033\XML Comments`) but changing it didn't affect the C# XML summary.

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369116/change-default-xml-comment-snippet-in-visual-studio) but the accepted answer doesn't really answer this question, and the second answer is outdated.

Comment: Good question but the fact that it's turned on/off in Tools,Options,C#,formatting suggests it isn't really a snippet. Also it adapts to your parameters and return type.

Comment: Yes @HenkHolterman is right, that's not a snippet - it actually was more of a macro I think - this may be helpful, this is a [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2709987-xml-comments-schema-customization-in-c) for this and still unresolved as it seems

Comment: @NSGaga Thanks. The `User Voice` is proof enough. From [a link there](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lisa/2010/05/24/how-to-customize-the-xml-comments-that-are-inserted-by-the-visual-basic-code-editor/) it seems it is, in a way, a snippet, but is only supported for VB, not C#.

Comment: @NSGaga Also, feel free to write an answer. I wrote mine because your response was a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by OP, not sure if it's an answer - but there doesn't seem to be a better one at the moment, unfortunately...

This may be helpful, this is a [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2709987-xml-comments-schema-customization-in-c) for this and still unresolved as it seems.

As per the @HenkHolterman's comment - that I agree with - I don't think that's a snippet. For the moment it seems to be built into VS (out of curiosity I searched through VS 15 - new version not the 2015, and nothing new in there either - I searched all files for anything resembling XML comments).

There's a [VB solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx) that, as I could see, places a custom .XML file in the specific AppData location - which doesn't work for C#. They describe the process as...

> Visual Studio has built-in defaults for the XML skeletons that get
>   inserted, but when VBXMLDoc.xml is present upon startup, Visual Studio
>   will use the XML definitions from that file instead

Answer (score 1):

As per [a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641034/where-is-the-snippet-for-a-methods-xml-summary/37642751#comment62764883_37641034) - there's a [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/2709987-xml-comments-schema-customization-in-c) request for it. And as per a comment on the User Voice - [it can be done in VB](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lisa/2010/05/24/how-to-customize-the-xml-comments-that-are-inserted-by-the-visual-basic-code-editor/) but not C#.